# How do I determine why my upright freezer won’t come back on once it shuts off?

Tags: repair, freezer

I replaced the controller and capacitor on compressor, but it still won’t cycle on. I banged on door slightly and it came on. It does this every time it goes off.

Any ideas on what I should check?

Comment: Have you checked the thermostat? Most are partly mechanical so the vibration is activating the switch.

Comment: No I haven’t. Not even sure where it is at or how to test it.  Thanks for any direction you can give me.

Comment: Have to bang the door slightly near the control panel. It is a Frigidaire upright with a control panel that just plugs in from the outside.

Answer (score 2):

The door switch probably has a problem. That switch not only controls the light, it is also used to turn off the fans and compressor if the door is open. If you banged it and it worked again, there is a wire or connection to it that is loose, or the contacts of the switch have corroded.